# R: replace values in data frame, in list

Tags: r

I would like to replace each value with proper name for all columns in each dataframe.
I tried this:

```
data <- lapply(myfilelist, function(x)
    {
        x <- dat_name[x[, ]]
        return(x)
    })
```

but it doesn't work (or it is possible only for one column but not for all of them at once).

example:

```
dat_name:

1 At5g001
2 At5g002
3 At5g003
4 At5g004
5 At5g005

ex.data.frame:
c1 c2 c3
3  2   1
4  5   2
1  0   3
0  0   4 
0  0   5
```

I would like:

```
data:

c1          c2       c3
At5g003  At5g002   At5g001
At5g004  At5g005   At5g002
At5g001  0         At5g003
0        0         At5g004 
0        0         At5g005
```

Could you help me please?

gosia

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected result based on that

Comment: Please do update it in your post using the edit button.  From the comments, it is difficult to get the format

Comment: sorry for the previous version

Comment: What is `dat_name`?  Is it a data.frame?

Comment: It is matrix: nrow=200, ncol=1

Comment: factor may help. `factor(dat_name)`

Comment: BTW, I assume that the numbers at the end of `At5g001` should match with the numbers in ex.data.frame, right?  Or is it just the row positions that needs to be matched?

Comment: the numbers at the end of At5g001 are random (in my data they are not the same as rows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- as.numeric(sub('.*g', '', dat_name[,1]))

data1 <- ex.data.frame
data1[] <- lapply(ex.data.frame, function(x) dat_name[,1][match(x, indx)])
data1
#      c1      c2      c3
#1 At5g003 At5g002 At5g001
#2 At5g004 At5g005 At5g002
#3 At5g001    <NA> At5g003
#4    <NA>    <NA> At5g004
#5    <NA>    <NA> At5g005
```

#### EDIT

If the strings as random, you could do

```
indx <- unlist(ex.data.frame)
is.na(indx) <- indx==0
data1 <- ex.data.frame
data1[] <- dat_name[,1][indx]
data1
#      c1      c2      c3
#1 At5g003 At5g002 At5g001
#2 At5g004 At5g005 At5g002
#3 At5g001    <NA> At5g003
#4    <NA>    <NA> At5g004
#5    <NA>    <NA> At5g005
```

Using the data from @plafort's post

```
indx <- unlist(ex.data.frame)
is.na(indx) <- indx==0
data1[] <- dat_name2[indx]
data1
#      c1      c2      c3
#1 At5g004 At5g012 At5g034
#2 At5g111 At5g999 At5g012
#3 At5g034    <NA> At5g004
#4    <NA>    <NA> At5g111
#5    <NA>    <NA> At5g999
```

#### data

```
dat_name <- structure(c("At5g001", "At5g002", "At5g003", "At5g004", 
 "At5g005"), .Dim = c(5L, 1L))

ex.data.frame <-  structure(list(c1 = c(3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
 c2 = c(2L, 5L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), c3 = 1:5), .Names = c("c1", "c2", "c3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: It works but what if: ex.data.frame is one data frame (has 3 columns)?

Comment: @gosia It is now one data.frame with `3 columns`.  Sorry, I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 2):

This may take care of the random values to be assigned:

```
lst <- lapply(ex.data.frame, function(x) factor(dat_name)[x])
maxx <- max(unlist(lapply(lst, length)))
newdf <- data.frame(lapply(lst, function(x) {length(x) <- maxx;x}))
newdf
# 
#        c1      c2      c3
# 1 At5g003 At5g002 At5g001
# 2 At5g004 At5g005 At5g002
# 3 At5g001    <NA> At5g003
# 4    <NA>    <NA> At5g004
# 5    <NA>    <NA> At5g005
```

Edit to test random values:

```
dat_name2 <- c('At5g034', 'At5g012', 'At5g004', 'At5g111', 'At5g999')
lst <- lapply(ex.data.frame, function(x) factor(dat_name2)[x])
maxx <- max(unlist(lapply(lst, length)))
newdf <- data.frame(lapply(lst, function(x) {length(x) <- maxx;x}))
newdf
       c1      c2      c3
1 At5g004 At5g012 At5g034
2 At5g111 At5g999 At5g012
3 At5g034    <NA> At5g004
4    <NA>    <NA> At5g111
5    <NA>    <NA> At5g999
```

It will still work because the 'level' of the factor is being matched by the order the data was entered into the `dat_name` vector. So `data_name[1]` is being mapped to `1` in the data frame. The expression is agnostic to the string of `dat_name`.

Comment: But what if the `data_name` elements are random. i.e. `set.seed(24); dat_name <- dat_name[sample(nrow(dat_name)),,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun I added a test of random values. It still works. I think the weakness in my code will come up if the `NA` or `0` values are mixed into the column values as in `df[,1] <- c(0,1,0,4,5)` because my length coercion will misalign the columns of lengths less than the max.

Comment: My comment was based on the assumption that the end numbers match with that of the elements in the ex.data.frame.  But, otherwise, it is okay

Comment: A minor comment is in `R 3.2.0`, you can use `lengths` i.e. `max(lengths(lst))`

Comment: Nice. Thank you! `max(unlist(lapply(lst, length)))` is such a mouthful.

Comment: @akrun Also as the OP mentioned, the values attached to the `At5g` strings are random so matching on a regex may be problematic.

Comment: That makes sense.  I updated with a possible option that doesn't rely on regex